# PhoneGap + Google Maps API v3 with key limited by Referers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, cordova

Is it possible to build PhoneGap + Google Maps JScript API application that uses an API key with allowed Referers list set to mydomain.com (it's just an example) ?
Wouldn't Google reject such API usage because of origin of requests is JScript stored locally in a device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe you are right, Google would reject requests from a PhoneGap app if the API key is limited to certain domain names, as when coming from a PhoneGap app, it is not coming from a domain name.

If were using the native Android or iOS Google Maps SDK, it looks like you can restrict it to the package names - you will see that option when creating a new Google Maps API key.

Answer (score -1):

In Google Maps API v3 you don't need an API key anymore. And yes - java script is cached locally on the device like any other page content.